# fopen doesn't work, program crashes

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to open a file with fopen, and i just don't see what's going wrong. The file is in the same directory as the main.c file. I've also tried using the full directory with same results. Thanks for your help

```
int main()
{
const char file[2000];

int numWords = 0;
scanf("%s", file);

//printf("good");
printf("%s", &file);

FILE *f;
f = fopen(&file, "r");

if(f == NULL)
{
    printf("Cant open");
    printf("\n%s", file);
    exit(2);
}
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and read them carefully.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change

```
printf("%s", &file);
```

and

```
f = fopen(&file, "r");
```

to

```
printf("%s", file);
```

and

```
f = fopen(file, "r");
```

Please follow the man pages for [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Your "&" are all misplaced. If you change it, that should work, roughly.

In future pay more attention to compiler warnings, please.

Comment: if you're compiling on linux, add -Wall to gcc args, once you are able to compile without warnings and have a program that executes without core'ing, use errno and strerror() for error reporting.

Comment: Useless answer, essentially translates to "It doesn't work because your code is wrong, once the code is correct it should work"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at an example of scanf at the bottom of this page. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Also it seems that you are fundamentally a bit confused on what a pointer is and where they belong. The & operator is actually the least commonly used of all pointer operators so don't expect to patter them all over the place like you have now.